# Redirect to custom module controller and render themplate from observer without changing my current browser Url

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I had written a observer to trap product view page event and it is working fine.Now i just want to load block from custom module controller without changing my current browser url so for that i am calling initForward() function with my custom module details but it is not working .The code for the try out is given below.

```
public function getProductView(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {         
          $resp = $observer->getEvent()->getFront()->getAction()->getRequest();
          $requestUri = $resp->getRequestString();            
           if ($resp->getActionName() == 'noRoute'){
              $request = Mage::app()->getRequest();
              $request->initForward()
                ->setControllerName('index')
                ->setModuleName('customproduct')
                ->setActionName('index')
                ->setDispatched(false);
              return false;


           }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my knowledege `initForward()` used in `controller_action_predispatch` event,,

You have to add event in you `config.xml`

```
 public function controllerActionPredispatch(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
        {         

            if (your condition here) {
                $request = $controller->getRequest();
                $request->initForward();
                $request->setControllerName('index');
                $request->setModuleName('customproduct');
                $request->setActionName('index')
                ->setDispatched(FALSE);
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you please tell me how can i achieve it.

Comment: check my edit @RupeshDeotale